# Toggle Checkboxes AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, angular-material

I am trying to make checkboxes appear when md-button Delete or Add is selected and to disappear when it is not. The checkbox is automatically hiding like it should because a button hasn't been pressed yet. When I press the buttons nothing happens. I am using Angular Material to build the app as well.

Any help is appreciated

**HTML**

```
<md-menu>
    <img src="/imagepathhere" ng-click="$mdMenu.open($event)">

    <md-menu-content ng-model="checkbox">
      <md-menu-item>
          <md-button value="add"><p>Add</p></md-button>
      </md-menu-item>

      <md-menu-item>
          <md-button value="delete"><p>Delete</p></md-button>
      </md-menu-item>
    </md-menu-content>
</md-menu>

<md-content flex class="md-whiteframe-1dp" ng-model="checkbox">

  <md-list>
    <md-list-item layout="row">
      <img class="md-avatar" src="/imagepathhere" />
      <div flex>
        <h3>Babe Ruth</h3>
      </div>

      <md-checkbox ng-if="checkbox == 'delete'" layout="row"></md-checkbox>

    </md-list-item>
</md-list>
```

Comment: which checkbox you want to hide?

Comment: can you post the angular code?

Comment: When what button is selected? which checkboxes, those `md-menu-item` inside the `<md-menu-content ng-model="checkbox">`?

Comment: I clarified my question, the checkbox is hiding. When Add or Delete is selected the checkbox should appear. I did something similar before where I defined the ng-model and when that model name == a value the ng-if would toggle ng-show and ng-hide. It is not currently doing that now.